# Suppose F is a field, and $f: F_F \to M$ is a non-zero homomorphism. Show that f is injective

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I'm having some trouble with this problem. The $F_F$ notation indicates that F is a right module, but I'm not really sure what it means for a ring or field to be a module of itself.

Heres' the question again:

Suppose F is a field, and $f: F_F \to M$ is a non-zero homomorphism. Show that f is injective

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A field $F$ can be viewed as a module, really a vector space, over itself by the induced field operations. Namely scalar multiplication is your ordinary multiplication in the field, and vector addition is addition of elements in the field. Distributive properties and the other vector space axioms all follow from the required field structure.

Now, can you prove that $\ker(f)$ is an ideal of $F_F$? What are the possible ideals in a field?

Comment: So I'm treating $F = F_F$? In that case, the only possible ideals in a field are $<1> and <0>$. $ker(f) = <0>$ (follows from the definiton of kernel??)

Then, the homomorphism must be injective. since $f(x) = f(y) iff (x-y) \in ker(f)$

Comment: @randomafk Yes, $F=F_F$, and those are the only possible ideals. However, $\ker(f)=(0)$ by the fact that $f$ is a nonzero homomorphism. $\ker(f)$ can be the whole domain $(1)$, but then it would be the zero homomorphism, contrary to the hypothesis.

Comment: the zero homomorphis is just f(r) = 0? Okay. That makes sense -- thanks a lot!